# Why this code is NOT throwing an undefined property PHP notice?

Tags: php, variables, pass-by-reference

Just playing around and I found this.

Why the call by reference to `$this->newAxis()` does **not** throw an undefined property notice (`xAxis` property), while the `var_dump()` does?

```php
public function newXAxis()
{
    // var_dump(isset($this->xAxis)); // false
    // var_dump($this->xAxis); // Throws the notice
    return $this->newAxis($this->xAxis); // Should throw the notice?!
}

protected function newAxis(&$current)
{
    // ...
}
```

Does it have something to do with the passing by reference, thus not accessing the property directly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it happens because you pass it by reference. When you pass by value, an attempt is made to actually read the value of the variable - so a notice appears. When you pass by reference, the value does not need to be read.

When you do that, the variable/property is created if it does not exist yet.

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php#example-277):

> If you assign, pass, or return an undefined variable by reference, it
> will get created.
>
> ```
> <?php
> function foo(&$var) { }
> foo($a); // $a is "created" and assigned to null
> ```

Comment: I love programming because you always learn something new. Thanks for the reference to the manual.

Answer (score 5):

```
newAxis(&$current)
```

is pass by reference. that means you are passing a variable.

By default all variables in PHP are undefined.

You define them by just using, e.g.

```
$a = 1;
```

As you can see, PHP does not complain here that `$a` is undefined, right?

Okay ;), see here:

```
$a = $b;
```

PHP now complains that `$b` is undefined.

Like with `$a` (you define the variable) and `$b` (the variable is not defined) it is with passing by reference or by value:

```
$this->newAxis($a);
```

The variable `$a` is defined when passed by reference. It carries it's default value `NULL`. And now the `$b` example:

```
var_dump($b);
```

`var_dump` takes it's parameters by value. Therefore PHP complains that `$b` is not defined.

And that's all. I hope it was clear enough.

Answer (score -2):

I'm going on a limb here...

Since you are accessing it as an object (from a class) it won't give you a notice, while when you var_dump something it kind of access it like an array (and since it's empty it throws a notice)